# Script which converts array into concatenated string separated by comma

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of all the email addresses stored in the LDAP database, separated by comma.

By simplifying this [script](https://bitbucket.org/zhb/iredmail/raw/cb7d2492563d/extra/update/updateLDAPValues_080_to_081.py) I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

# Author:   Zhang Huangbin <zhb _at_ iredmail.org>
# Purpose:  Add enabledService=lib-storage for all mail users.
#           Required by IMAP folder sharing in Dovecot-2.0.
# Date:     2012-05-18

import sys
import ldap

# Note:
#   * bind_dn must have write privilege on LDAP server.
uri = 'ldap://127.0.0.1:389'
basedn = 'o=domains,dc=example,dc=com'
bind_dn = 'cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com'
bind_pw = 'password'

# Initialize LDAP connection.
print >> sys.stderr, "* Connecting to LDAP server: %s" % uri
conn = ldap.initialize(uri=uri, trace_level=0,)
conn.bind_s(bind_dn, bind_pw)

# Get all mail users.
print >> sys.stderr, "* Get all mail accounts..."
allUsers = conn.search_s(
        basedn,
        ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
        "(objectClass=mailUser)",
        ['mail', 'enabledService'],
        )

total = len(allUsers)
print >> sys.stderr, "* Total %d user(s)." % (total)

# Counter.
count = 1

for user in allUsers:
    (dn, entry) = user
    mail = entry['mail'][0]

    print >> "%s, " % (mail)

    count += 1

# Unbind connection.
conn.unbind()
```

When I run this I get error:

> - Connecting to LDAP server: ldap://127.0.0.1:389
> - Get all mail accounts...
> - Total 64 user(s). Traceback (most recent call last):   File "list_mail_users.py", line 43, in 
>     print >> "%s, " % (mail) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

I asked this question on the support forum and they suggest I use: ldapsearch instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem

```
for user in allUsers:
  (dn, entry) = user
  mail = entry['mail'][0]

  print >> "%s, " % (mail)

  count += 1
```

You are trying to print to "%s, ", which is a string, print only can accept objects with a write attribute.  I'm not exactly certain what you are trying to do with that, but I would expect something like `print >> sys.stdout, "%s, " %(mail)` or maybe `print >> File "%s, "%mail`

Comment: Also, I would expect you to probably want ', '.join(mail) as what to print, instead of "%s, "